# How would I convert the raw 256bit integers generated in an ECC program into valid ECDSA keys?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, openvpn, ecdsa

I've written a python program that (using the secp256k1 parameters) generates the 256bit integer needed for the private key, along with the final point for the public key. The final point is coded as an object with the x and y values being properties inside. Here's is an example key pair in hex:

```
Private Key: 0xdce522c55f05554b60effd15225ae3984f8573d42da2332f2e76293ef366f9b6
Public Key: (0xc733e7c88c3497d343a2ebb0adf05cd0f1656cc6b12e1d3f8d6573e50cb0f23a, 0x1e179403d4118ab406abe70287e0e442b994877a5aeb21e5a2ae217cf6ec72c7)
```

My goal is to export the python program as a binary executable file and configure OpenVPN to use this instead of the in-built ECC key generator. From what I've found online the ECC keys used by OpenVPN are not *just* encoded with the 256bit integers, but also contain additional information about the curve used as well as other properties.

Would there be a way of converting the values my program generates into valid OpenVPN ECC keys?

Comment: Uh, for what purpose? I see ECDSA and not ECDH, so you mean that you want to create an X.509 certificate that uses this particular public key? Basically OpenVPN uses TLS as far as I know, so you'd have to create an X.509v3 certificate that is usable as client or server certificate. For the server cert it should also include things like the host name.

Comment: Do you maybe need OpenSSL compatible keys so you can use them to generate such a certificate? I've voted to close as there isn't one specific way of expressing a key.